# How to get index of datetime within a pandas DateTimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

Is there a way to directly get the index of a certain `datetime` within a `DateTimeIndex`?

I have following toy example code which does what I want after I convert the `DateTimeIndex` to a `list`.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

year = 2020
minutesStep = 10
dateTimeStr = "2020-01-01 00:40:00"

datesTimes = pd.date_range(start='1/1/'+str(year), end='1/1/'+str(year+1), freq=str(minutesStep)+'min')
dateTimeObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTimeStr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

l = datesTimes.tolist()
i = l.index(dateTimeObj)
print i
print datesTimes[i]
```

This outputs what is expected:

```
>>> 
4
2020-01-01 00:40:00
```

However I would like to get the index directly from the `DateTimeIndex`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the index of a particular `datetime` within a `pandas` `DateTimeIndex` is possible using the `get_loc` function as follows:

```
j = datesTimes.get_loc(dateTimeObj)
print j
print datesTimes[j]
```

Which outputs as well what is expected:

```
>>> 
4
2020-01-01 00:40:00
```